# Toggle NERDCommenter to Alternative Value Based on File Type

Tags: vim, autocmd

I'd like to configure NERDCommenter in vim to use the alternative comment styles for certain file types. What is the correct way to do this. I can't figure out how to call into the plugin code from the `autocmd`. What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
autocmd FileType dosbatch :call NERDCommenterAltDelims
```

The above fails to work, but I found out I can get the function name with the command:

```
map <Plug>NERDCommenterAltDelims
```

that returns:

```
:call <SNR>17_SwitchToAlternativeDelimiters(1)<CR>
```

Is there some way to use the map command to execute the value of the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, why don't you just switch the default and alt definitions for the `dosbatch` filetype, as NERDCommenter offers this extension point. Put the following into your `~/.vimrc`; it must be executed *before* `plugin/NERDCommenter.vim`.

```
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = {'dosbatch': { 'left': '::', 'leftAlt': 'REM ' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only the script-local function, you have to invoke the provided `<Plug>` mapping via `:normal`:

```
:autocmd FileType dosbatch execute "normal \<Plug>NERDCommenterAltDelims"
```

To suppress the `Now using ... to delimit comments` message, use `silent execute` instead.

Comment: Great answer since it calls the function in question. The only problem, is that when the autocmd executes, I don't think the plugin has loaded yet. Is there anyway to chain this with VimEnter?

Comment: Huh? The `FileType` event is fired whenever a batch file is detected. The inital load of plugins happened before that (and before `VimEnter` on startup. Anyway, I would prefer my other solution because it only needs to run once.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @ingo-karkat answer:

```
autocmd FileType dosbatch autocmd VimEnter * execute "normal \<Plug>NERDCommenterAltDelims"
```

My vimscript skills are non-existant, so there might be a cleaner way to do this. Feel free to improve upon it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is now a new better way to use the functionality of NERDCommenter in our own mappings:

```
call NERDComment('n', 'altDelims')
```

See:

```
:h NERDComNERDComment
```